# Capital Gains tax when moving for school

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax, home-ownership

My wife and I purchased our home in August of 2014, but now she has been accepted into a doctoral degree program 200 miles away, so we need to sell the house and move.  Unfortunately, we might be selling it prior to August 2016... depending on how quick our house sells.

As far as Capital Gains tax is concerned... we will not have resided in it for "at least 2 years in a 5 year period."

I'm wondering if moving for school would count as a "unforseen circumstance" for the IRS to allow us to exclude any capital gains?  I can't find any specific examples of this scenario with a definitive answer using my Google-fu.

Thanks!

Comment: Moving for school is, to use thge medical analogy, elective rather than fgorced. You could keep the house and do a long commute, or rent it out while you are away, or several other solutions.Or you could not go to thast school, or study remotely.... Definitely not unforeseen circumstances in this sense.

Comment: If it doesn't sell the day you list it, it's not unreasonable for you to put "September 1 closing date" in your counter offer.

Comment: @user662852 - why would you put that in a counter offer, you could just put that in the contract that settlement needs to be at least Sept 1st. But where I come from the dates for Capital Gains are base on when the contract is signed and exchanged and not on the settlement date. Is this different in the USA?

Comment: @Victor 1. the 1099-S reports day of closing: https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701.html;  I suppose nothing stops a seller from doing accrual accounting if they care to.  2. In the U.S. the buyer prepares the first offer.  The seller can sign it or return a counter offer.  This iterates until there is a contract both parties can sign.

Comment: @user662852 - if you are waiting for negotiation to place a longer settlement date in the contract then you may lose on an other aspect of the negotiations - such as with a lower price, so again why not specify it upfront into the contract before any negotiations begin. In many instances the initial contract is not changed much and negotiations are purely on price.

Comment: @Victor this is getting far afIeld from the OP.  The OP can easily determine the extra time value of a delay to September to keep the cap gains exclusion; and weigh any further buyer counters at a lower price in an economically rational calculation.  An emotional buyer may not reduce. Or, call it a "win win".  Given the variety of financing contingencies that are common in US buyer offers, it's not typical for the seller to make the first signed legally binding offer with all terms, waiting for some possibly unqualified dude off the street to sign and tie up the sale.

Comment: @user662852 - if I was interested in a property and viewed the contract which had a standard settlement period, then made an offer and the vendor made a counter offer extending the settlement period considerably, I would take the opportunity to either remove my offer or lower it considerably. If on the other hand the extended settlement was already in the original contract, then I would take that into consideration from the start and probably make a similar offer to what I would have made if the settlement period was standard.

Comment: @Victor i don't understand.  A listing in the MLS database is not a binding contract.  There is no contract to view.  The buyer makes the first candidate contract.   Most settlements take over 60 days unless the buyer is a cash buyer.  We're about 130 days from Sept  today.   The OP stated "we might" so i assumed they are not on the market and unlikely to list "today". If they take 2-3 weeks to clean, paint, etc, and take 1-2 weeks for a qualified offer, to reiterate my original comment, it would not be unreasonable to counter with Sept 1 (or the August anniversary date of first buy)

Comment: Where I am from you need to have a Contract for Sale of Land prepared before you get a Real Estate Agent to list your property for sale. And the standard settlement is 6 weeks (42 days).

Comment: We seem to be drifting off the question that was asked...?

Comment: How can you list a property for sale if there is no contract prepared????

Comment: @Victor sounds like you have material to start a new question about real estate sales process in the US.  I will look for that instead of responding in comments

Comment: Are you sure you have a gain? A typical 5% to the agent, plus lawyer costs, you may have so little gain the tax isn't worth strategizing over. On the other hand, a huge gain can be avoided by a divorce. (And spend the savings on a vacation to celebrate the remarriage.)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer haha, that is one route I had not thought to take!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no. Your move is voluntary.

https://www.irs.gov/uac/IRS-Issues-Home-Sale-Exclusion-Rules

However, you may still have options.

You may be able to rent an apartment near your wife's school and retain use of your current house as your 'main home' by IRS definition and keep it eligible as your primary residence through August. This is a gray area, since your 'primary residence' and 'main home' are defined circumstantially *and* factually. Definitely seek professional counsel if you decide to do this.

https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523/ar02.html#en_US_2015_publink1000200611

This will be plenty of hassle and extra $$, so make sure your tax savings will be worth it.

Otherwise, this is a short-term expense for a better career path! Congratulations!

Comment: Or you stay in the house until September, wife rents an apartment (or room, for cheaper) and comes home on weekends.  That also gives you time for job hunting or whatever else you need to do for the move.

Comment: @jamesqf Exactly. That may qualify you for the exemption. Of course, the expense of the rental and the travel had better be cheaper than your tax savings!

Comment: @jkuz this is exactly what I was looking for.  To us, it feels like our options are limited because the field she is going for (veterinary medicine) is so cut-throat and you really just have to take what you can get... but to the government, it is a voluntary decision.  Thanks!